# How to disable AudioContext API in JavaScript (for Firefox extension)?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to disable the AudioContext API in JavaScript (for Firefox extension). I've tried making the function and returning false. I have tried everything. I want to stop a new object from AudioContext.

Comment: I don't understand the question, maybe I am not the right person to answer but I've dealt with AudioContext, what is "making the function" is it do you mean calling the function or constructor as in AudioContext()? Are you trying to disable the output of an oscillator or something?